# In Java, should variables be declared at the top of a function, or as they're needed?

Tags: java, syntax, variables, coding-style

I'm cleaning up Java code for someone who starts their functions by declaring all variables up top, and initializing them to null/0/whatever, as opposed to declaring them as they're needed later on.

What are the specific guidelines for this? Are there optimization reasons for one way or the other, or is one way just good practice? Are there any cases where it's acceptable to deviate from whatever the proper way of doing it is?

Answer (score 98):

Declare variables as close to the first spot that you use them as possible.  It's not really anything to do with efficiency, but makes your code much more readable.  The closer a variable is declared to where it is used, the less scrolling/searching you have to do when reading the code later.  Declaring variables closer to the first spot they're used will also naturally narrow their [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29#Scope_and_extent).

Comment: Tip: if you use Visual Studio highlight a variable anywhere and hit F12 will take you to its definition (Shift + F12 will find all references).

Answer (score 44):

The proper way is to declare variables exactly when they are first used and minimize their scope in order to make the code easier to understand.

Declaring variables at the top of functions is a holdover from C (where it was required), and has absolutely no advantages (variable scope exists only in the source code, in the byte code all local variables exist in sequence on the stack anyway). Just don't do it, ever.

Some people may try to defend the practice by claiming that it is "neater", but any need to "organize" code within a method is usually a strong indication that the method is simply too long.

Answer (score 20):

From the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), [Chapter 6 on Declarations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html):

> 6.3    Placement
>
> Put declarations only at the beginning
>   of blocks. (A block is any code
>   surrounded by curly braces "{" and
>   "}".) Don't wait to declare variables
>   until their first use; it can confuse
>   the unwary programmer and hamper code
>   portability within the scope.
>
> ```
> void myMethod() {
>     int int1 = 0;         // beginning of method block
>
>     if (condition) {
>         int int2 = 0;     // beginning of "if" block
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The one exception to the rule is
>   indexes of for loops, which in Java
>   can be declared in the for statement:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++) { ... }
> ```
>
> Avoid local declarations that hide
>   declarations at higher levels. For
>   example, do not declare the same
>   variable name in an inner block:
>
> ```
> int count;
> ...
> myMethod() {
>     if (condition) {
>         int count = 0;     // AVOID!
>         ...
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Shame on you, Sun, shame on you!

Comment: *The above is provided as reference only. Neither of you is wrong/right, but personally I like Bill & S.Lott's answers best*

Comment: I suspect that this text is very old, with "confuse the unwary programmer" referring to large numbers of C programmers new to Java. Nowadays this case is very rare, but the text was never revised.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. I´m neither from java world nor from C world, I just prefer it. As usual, you guys are debating over something that´s just a matter of preference...

Answer (score 14):

If you have a kabillion variables used in various isolated places down inside the body of a function, your function is too big.

If your function is a comfortably understandable size, there's no difference between "all up front" and "just as needed".

The only not-up-front variable would be in the body of a `for` statement.

```java
for( Iterator i= someObject.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
```

Comment: I was about to write something similar.  Only thing I'd add is that I sometimes deviate from declaring at the beginning of the method if I'm declaring a variable only applicable to a particular block within the method (e.g. within an else statement block).

Comment: @Adamski: The "in an else block" vs. "in an if block" variables are very, very rare.  The `if` and `else` structures must have parallel side-effects and a one-side-only local variable is a real rarity.

Answer (score 9):

From [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html):

> **4.8.2.2 Declared when needed**
>
> Local variables are not habitually declared at the start of their
> containing block or block-like construct. Instead, local variables are
> declared close to the point they are first used (within reason), to
> minimize their scope. Local variable declarations typically have
> initializers, or are initialized immediately after declaration.

Well, I'd follow what Google does, on a superficial level it might seem that declaring all variables at the top of the method/function would be "neater", it's quite apparent that it'd be beneficial to declare variables as necessary. It's subjective though, whatever feels intuitive to you.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that declaring them as-needed results in fewer mistakes than declaring them at the beginning. I've also found that declaring them at the minimum scope possible to also prevent mistakes.

When I looked at the byte-code generated by the location of the declaration few years ago, I found they were more-or-less identical. There were occasionally differences depending on when they were assigned. Even something like:

```java
for(Object o : list) {
   Object temp = ...;  //was not "redeclared" every loop iteration
}
```

vs

```java
Object temp;
for(Object o : list) {
   temp = ...; //nearly identical bytecode, if not exactly identical.
}
```

Came out more or less identical

Comment: It's also easier to refactor code (Extract snippets of code into methods) when variables are declared as needed.

Answer (score 5):

I am doing this very same thing at the moment. All of the variables in the code that I am reworking are declared at the top of the function. I've seen as I've been looking through this that several variables are declared but NEVER used or they are declared and operations are being done with them (ie parsing a `String` and then setting a `Calendar` object with the date/time values from the string) but then the resulting `Calendar` object is NEVER used.

I am going through and cleaning these up by taking the declarations from the top and moving them down in the function to a spot closer to where it is used.

Comment: Jeremy - I don't know what build tool you're using, but eclipse has an option to warn you when a local variable is never used - it's just a simple two-click process to remove those :)

Comment: Most of the IDE tools I've seen won't catch a conceptually-not-used, such as "MyObject o = new MyObject(); o.SetFlag(true);" and then never used again. Sure, it was technically used, but may not serve any real purpose.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002 - I'm not using a build tool. I'm in an environment that uses jsp pages that when executed generate vxml and return them to the vxml browser. The editor in this environment doesn't have a compiler so even simple syntax errors aren't caught until I deploy it to the test server. I've gotten around this by writing some in BlueJ and some in Notepad++ but I've just come to accept the fact that this is a bad development environment. Luckily the next release of this environment uses Eclipse.

Comment: @James Schek, This is just an update comment. James comment is no longer true for eclipse at least.

Answer (score 5):

Defining variable in a wider scope than needed hinders understandability quite a bit. Limited scope signals that this variable has meaning for only this small block of code and you can not think about when reading further. This is a pretty important issue because of the tiny short-term working memory that the brain has (it said that on average you can keep track of only 7 things). One less thing to keep track of is significant.

Similarly you really should try to avoid variables in the literal sense. Try to assign all things once, and declare them final so this is known to the reader. Not having to keep track whether something changes or not really cuts the cognitive load.

Answer (score 5):

Principle: Place local variable declarations as close to their first use as possible, and NOT simply at the top of a method. Consider this example:

```
/** Return true iff s is a blah or a blub. */
public boolean checkB(String s) {
    // Return true if s is a blah
    ... code to return true if s is a blah ... 

    // Return true if s is a blub. */
    int helpblub= s.length() + 1;
    ... rest of code to return true is s is a blah.

    return false;
}
```

Here, local variable helpblub is placed where it is necessary, in the code to test whether s is a blub. It is part of the code that implements "Return true is s is a blub".
It makes absolutely no logical sense to put the declaration of helpblub as the first statement of the method. The poor reader would wonder, why is that variable there? What is it for?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is actually objectively provable that the declare-at-the-top style is more error-prone.

If you mutate-test code in either style by moving lines around at random (to simulate a merge gone bad or someone unthinkingly cut+pasting), then the declare-at-the-top style has a greater chance of compiling while functionally wrong.

I don't think declare-at-the-top has any corresponding advantage that doesn't come down to personal preference.

So assuming you want to write reliable code, learn to prefer doing just-in-time declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Its a matter of readability and personal preference rather than performance. The compiler does not care and will generate the same code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people declare at the top and at the bottom of functions. I prefer the top, where I can see them quickly. It's a matter of choice and preference.

Comment: Are you thinking the top and bottom of classes?  You can't really declare a variable at the bottom of a function (after it's used).  When I read his question I was thinking of member variables and not method variables--so maybe that's what you are thinking too...