# What is the current best practice following the addEvent() saga?

Tags: javascript, standards, ecmascript-5

There seem to be endless pages of writing and comment threads about `addEvent` implementations in Javascript, going back many years.

What should I be using *today*, in `currentTime.getFullYear()`, for the most versatile, simple cross-browser `addEvent` implementation?  What is the best practice?  Is there a standard anywhere on the horizon?

Is google's [base2](https://code.google.com/p/base2/) library a panacea for this problem?

Background:
[Crossbrowser DOM Scripting: Event Handlers](http://www.scottandrew.com/weblog/articles/cbs-events)
[addEvent() considered harmful](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html) 
[addEvent() recoding contest](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/addevent_recodi.html)
[Flexible Javascript Events](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/)
[A problem with John Resig's addEvent](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2007/03/28/a-problem-with-john-resigs-addevent)
[addEvent() – My Solution](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/)

Comment: You want to create custom event? or using events like `onClick` and such..?

Comment: Not much changed over the years except that more browsers support standard `addEventListener` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9+ all support `window.addEventListener` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

To support everyone else you have to do some fanciness to support both it and `window.attachEvent`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6925427/496735

Comment: Restating the question, then, is there a current, best "fanciness" somewhere?