# What is the best/standard addEventListener workaround for IE that handles memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, addeventlistener, attachevent

During my extensive research, I have seen many workarounds handling this issue. ([**See this SO post for some good links**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046128/what-is-the-current-best-practice-following-the-addevent-saga).) My main concern is handling the memory leaks that come from using `attachEvent()` in IE. Anyways, after all of my research I found this workaround:

```
// written by Dean Edwards, 2005
// with input from Tino Zijdel - crisp@xs4all.nl
// http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/
function addEvent(element, type, handler)
{
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else
    {
        if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = addEvent.guid++;
        if (!element.events) element.events = {};
        var handlers = element.events[type];
        if (!handlers)
        {
            handlers = element.events[type] = {};
            if (element['on' + type]) handlers[0] = element['on' + type];
            element['on' + type] = handleEvent;
        }

        handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
    }
}
addEvent.guid = 1;

function removeEvent(element, type, handler)
{
    if (element.removeEventListener)
        element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else if (element.events && element.events[type] && handler.$$guid)
        delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
}

function handleEvent(event)
{
    event = event || fixEvent(window.event);
    var returnValue = true;
    var handlers = this.events[event.type];

    for (var i in handlers)
    {
        if (!Object.prototype[i])
        {
            this.$$handler = handlers[i];
            if (this.$$handler(event) === false) returnValue = false;
        }
    }

    if (this.$$handler) this.$$handler = null;

    return returnValue;
}

function fixEvent(event)
{
    event.preventDefault = fixEvent.preventDefault;
    event.stopPropagation = fixEvent.stopPropagation;
    return event;
}
fixEvent.preventDefault = function()
{
    this.returnValue = false;
}
fixEvent.stopPropagation = function()
{
    this.cancelBubble = true;
}

// This little snippet fixes the problem that the onload attribute on the body-element will overwrite
// previous attached events on the window object for the onload event
if (!window.addEventListener)
{
    document.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (window.onload && window.onload != handleEvent)
        {
            addEvent(window, 'load', window.onload);
            window.onload = handleEvent;
        }
    }
}​
```

Now I have a few questions. It wasn't easy to find this code so I can assume that not many people are using this code. That leads me to believe that others are using different pieces of code and are having no problems with their code. If this is the case, then is this code that I just posted overkill?

I'm also concerned that in my research I found tons and tons of workarounds similar to this:

```
if (el.addEventListener){  
  el.addEventListener('click', callback, false);   
} else if (el.attachEvent){  
  el.attachEvent('onclick', callback);  
}
```

This piece of code does not handle the memory leaks caused by IE. So now onto my question: **What is the best/standard workaround using plain JavaScript to handle `attachEvent()` and it's memory leaks in IE?**

Comment: Do you realize that leaks of this kind are only an issue in older browsers if you are dynamically removing and creating DOM objects that have event handlers attached and are doing it enough times to make the leak material (e.g. hundreds of megabytes).

Comment: @jfriend00 -- part of the issue with GhettoIE was that it didn't even release the memory when you went to the next page: other peoples' sites could contribute to a memory leak on your page. Pretty crappy, that. @Aust -- The only time this was a problem was when you had circular references: If you have an element with an `onclick`, and that `onclick`'s function has a variable pre-stored in a closure which points back to the same element. Just null all of your `element` references when you're done with them and don't keep elements in closures in OldIE, if you're using the closure in an event.

Comment: @Norguard - what's the latest version of IE that didn't release this memory when you went to another page?  And, how much memory did one event handler cost?

Comment: The rest of the script you've got there isn't necessarily for memory-leaks, but for making `removeEventListener` useful by keeping reference to the function, in case you need to remove it (because you never get a handle or get access to the stored array of handlers -- you need to give it the exact version of the exact function, which is hard if you needed to bind context, or create a closure, et cetera).

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't rightly remember when it 100% stopped. I ***DO*** know that if you spend too much time worrying about it, then you're worrying about a problem that really reached its peak *before* IE6. And like you said, it would take hundreds or thousands of handled nodes, on a crappy PC, before IE just died...  ...but that's also added up over every page you visit. IE6 and IE7 are leaky, but I think that both of them were free of the memory-hole. Even if IE6 suffered, we're trying to get that thing to die, anyway. Poor performance is expected, by now.

Comment: @Norguard - that's kind of what I thought.  So, the big problem was before IE6.  Do you think this issue is still worth worrying about any more? IE6 is pretty much dead in most parts of the world (below 1% in the U.S.).  IE7 seems to be dying quickly too.  FWIW, Facebook no longer supports IE6 or IE7.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well, WP7 users, who still haven't updated to 7.5 (like my wife...) are still on IE7. If you're doing corporate intranet apps, and you're all stuck on XP and IE6/IE7...  ...if you're a "low-level" (*not really) JavaScript dev, who needs to work with embedded systems, or on edge-case phones, or the like, then yes, you should know these things. If you're a jQuery guy who does UI and knows how to cache their references, knows how to delegate and defer events, sandboxes their stuff and cleans up after themselves, then not really, no. Those other things are far more important, today.