# How to Show an Alert when Option is Selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I'm trying to alert visitors about a minimum amount, and I just reached the point where I can show the alert, but for all changes... 
The point is that I want only to show the alert when the user clicks on option value = 1.

Here's what I've got (missing the IF clause):

```
<script> 
    function MinPecas(quantidade) {
        alert("MÍNIMO DE 30 PEÇAS PARA ORÇAMENTO");
    }  
</script>

<select name="quantidade" id="quantidade" onchange ="MinPecas(this.form)">
<option value="1">0 A 30 PÇS</option>
<option value="2">30 A 50 PÇS</option>
<option value="3">50 A 100 PÇS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `if ( value == "1" ) alert()` ???

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove that option, if it's not available? It's like saying:  _"Want some candy? Oh, sorry, I don't have any candy..."_ **Edit:** @Guilherme Alright then ;)

Comment: Actually not because they can select the 0 up to 30 pieces, but need to be aware of this condition.

Comment: if ( value == "1" ) alert() didn't work...

Comment: yes, because you don't have 'value' variable, you have quantidade, simple replacing would solve it... however: http://jsfiddle.net/z7p1np23/

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to change on comment to quantidade, but didnt work aswell.

Comment: Place code before </body> tag closing - it will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925146/best-practice-on-adding-event-listeners-javascript-html) to apply event listeners from the Javascript itself, as opposed to directly in the HTML. For this reason, use the `element.addEventListener()` method. If you pass it the event (`change`) function (`MinPecas`), it will call `MinPecas` whenever the value of the element is changed. Additionally, the `this` variable of the function will then be the element, so `this.value` will be equal to the value of the element. You can get the element using `document.getElementById()`, and then adding the event listener to that.

```
<select name="quantidade" id="quantidade">
    <option value="1">0 A 30 PÇS</option>
    <option value="2">30 A 50 PÇS</option>
    <option value="3">50 A 100 PÇS</option>
</select> 

<script> 
    function MinPecas(){
        if (this.value === '1'){
            alert("MÍNIMO DE 30 PEÇAS PARA ORÇAMENTO");
        }
     }

     document.getElementById('quantidade').addEventListener('change', MinPecas);

</script>
```

Lastly, you'll want to make sure that the `<script>` element is *after* the `<select>`, because if it runs beforehand, the select tag will not exist yet and the `document.getElementById('quantidade')` will not be able to find it and won't return anything.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: @GuilhermeAndredosSantos great! You might also want to consider adding `selected="selected"` to the second `<option>` tag because as of now, the option that is selected by default is "0 A 30 PÇS".  
  
`<option value="2" selected="selected">30 A 50 PÇS</option>`

Comment: Actually, I have 10 options, and I set the selected option to the 3rd one. But thanks for the clue! Helped me a lot... Now I'll apply it to other forms...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
<script> 
    function MinPecas(quantidade){
     if(quantidade == 1)
          alert("MÍNIMO DE 30 PEÇAS PARA ORÇAMENTO");

    }  
    </script>

<select onchange="MinPecas(this.value)" name="quantidade">
<option value="1">0 A 30 PÇS</option>
<option value="2">30 A 50 PÇS</option>
<option value="3">50 A 100 PÇS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! The point was that I should place the script after the select option clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=quantidade]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
             alert();
        }
    });
 });
```

**EDIT**

Also for this to work you need to include jquery library!

Since you want the alert to be displayed when the element with value 1 is SELECTED try adding an empty option as the first choice.

```
<option>Please select</option>
```

Comment: Isn't better to use just `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` ? :)

Comment: @CookieMan It's a valid optimization, but a tiny one which will go unnoticed by real users.

Comment: You'll also need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), since the `<script>` is before the HTML.

Comment: So I need to place the script content before the body clause?

Comment: It's good practice to use strict equality:
`$(this).val() === '1'`