# How to display palindromes?

Tags: java

I want to display palindromes for the product of two, 3 digit numbers, ranging from 100-999. Something is wrong with my code, I can't quite place it.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   int num = 0, remainder = 0, sum = 0, b;
   int temp;

   for (b = 999; b >= 100; b--) {
      for (a = 999; a >= 100; a--) {
         num = (a * b);
         temp = num;

         while (num > 0) { 
            remainder = num % 10;  
            sum = (sum * 10) + remainder;    
            num = num / 10;
         }

         if (temp == sum)   
            System.out.println(temp);           
      }
   }
}
```

I expect an output, but I do not get any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code never resets `sum` to zero. [Declaring variables at the point of first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411463/in-java-should-variables-be-declared-at-the-top-of-a-function-or-as-theyre-ne) helps avoid this kind of problem.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int b = 999; b >= 100; b--) {
    for (int a = 999; a >= 100; a--) {
      int sum = 0;
      int num = (a * b);
      int temp = num;

      while (num > 0) {
        int remainder = num % 10;
        sum = (sum * 10) + remainder;
        num = num / 10;
      }

      if (temp == sum) {
        System.out.println(temp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied your file, and right before your if-statement, I put this line in my copy:

`System.out.println(temp + " " + sum);`

So, after running the code, here were the results.

(it counts up each time the print statement is ran)

Format: temp, sum

`1. temp = 98488, sum = -714680119`

`2. temp = 98384, sum = 243953829`

`3. temp = 98280, sum =  -31332991`

`>4000. temp = 10000, sum = -110845663`

Your `temp` is never equal to your `sum`, which means that your if statement will never run your print command. Here is a link to a pastebin which will contain all of the results. It is so long that I am not allowed to place it here (if I could nobody would want to read it) https://pastebin.com/7WxYKdgy

This is likely because of integer overflow. Learn more. [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)